# Is it OK to write a matrix-vector equation where the dimensions don't match?

Tags: linear-algebra, signal-processing

I am reading a PhD thesis which contains the following paragraph

[dimensions don't match](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxBea.png)

It is evident that the dimensions of the matrix and vectors don't match for $\mathbf{y}_k$, where $\mathbf{G}_{kl}\in\mathbb{C}^{N\times N}$, while $\mathbf{h}_k\in\mathbb{C}^M$. As far I understand, this is not allowed, however given that $\mathbf{h}_k^H\mathbf{w}_l$ is a scalar, since $\mathbf{w}_l\in\mathbb{C}^M$ as well, will this make this operation valid?

Comment: Please write out the paragraph here, instead of asking users to chase links offsite.

Comment: What is the dimension of $s_l$?

Comment: @gerw $N\times 1$

Comment: @GerryMyerson I used the stack exchange editor option to attach the image. It's not an offsite image :-)

Comment: if $hw$ is a scalar, then it's all good.

Comment: Either "Dimensions DO NOT match & It is wrong" or "Dimensions DO match & It is right" : There is no other alternative.

Comment: @AlvinL Still horrendous notation, though.

Comment: I am confused again as I got contradicting answers

Comment: It's of the form $(hw)Gs$, where $G$ is $n\times n$, $s$ is $n\times 1$ and $hw$ is a scalar. This is fine.

Comment: OK, can we extend this to write $$\mathbf{y}=\left[\mathbf{y}_1^T,\,\mathbf{y}_2^T,\,\cdots,\,\mathbf{y}_K^T\right]^T$$ in a compact form?

Comment: @Klaus This is rather standard notation in signal processing or the like. The notation is pretty self-explanatory when we know the field.

Comment: @AlvinL No this is engineering. Signal processing most likely.

Comment: @KBS That's correct. It's related to signal processing. It's physical-layer wireless communication to be more specific.

Comment: @Math_Novice I have added the corresponding tag. Please make sure put the right tags so that the right people see your post. This would have avoided such a long discussion in the comments.

Comment: There's another reason for writing it out here instead of linking to an image, Math_N; it will turn up on searches if it's written out here.

Comment: @KBS I will next time. Thanks for pointing this out

Comment: @GerryMyerson Good point. Next time I will summarize the relevant equations here. I guess I wanted to show this is in a PhD dissertation without actually referencing it.